# The problem of Transformer::lookupTransform

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I follow the tf tutorial and try to understand the frame transformation in ROS. But I'm confusing about the API `Transformer::lookupTransform`  and `tf_echo`
First, the usage of tf_echo is shown below.

Usage: tf_echo source_frame target_frame

This will echo the transform from the coordinate frame of the source_frame to the coordinate frame of the target_frame.

So it is clear, I will get the transform that from source_frame to target_frame. I also confirmed it in turtlesim. However, when I saw the [tutorial for tf_echo](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf). They say the `tf_echo` will return "the transform of the turtle2 frame with respect to turtle1 frame". In other words, I should get the transform from `target frame` to `source frame`. It is not correct since I verified from the turtlesim.

I  wen to see how to get transform. It is clear that in [tf_echo.cpp](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/indigo-devel/tf/src/tf_echo.cpp#L89). Everything is fine except this line.

`echoListener.tf.lookupTransform(source_frameid, target_frameid, ros::Time(), echo_transform);`

I compare this line with the API document.

`void Transformer::lookupTransform   (   const std::string &     target_frame, const std::string &     source_frame, const ros::Time &   time, StampedTransform &      transform  )`

With my inspection, `Transformer::lookupTransform` will get the transform that from target_frame to source_frame(API naming). However, for some reason, tf_echo swap the these frames. My questions are:

1)What is the meaning of source frame and target frame?

2)Why the usage of tf_echo is different from [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf)

3)Why tf_echo swap the arguments?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194046/the-problem-of-transformer::lookuptransform/) by [fboris](https://answers.ros.org/users/12101/fboris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The lookup API is named with respect to transforming data from the source frame into the target frame.

When referring to transform between coordinate frames  (transforming the frames, it is the inverse of the transform of data between the two frames)

Depending on the documentation if you're referring to the transform value for the data, or the transform value of the coordinate frames you get the inverse value.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fboris](https://answers.ros.org/users/12101/fboris/) on 2014-10-03**:
According to [tf_echo tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf) and command line usage, tf_echo should return me the transform that transformed the source frame to target frame. But the direction of transform is opposite. Do I misunderstand something?

**Comment by [fboris](https://answers.ros.org/users/12101/fboris/) on 2014-10-04**:
Moreover, can I expect the transformation like this ([http://i.imgur.com/2MWJnUF.png](https://i.imgur.com/2MWJnUF.png)) that will be returned by lookup API?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-04**:
That is what the lookup API gives you. The tf_echo give you the inverse, which is the transform to move the coordinate frames as a parallel to the published transforms for easier publishing debugging.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, the documentation of the API is missing one important aspect: It does not explicitely state, which of these transforms are active or passive (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation)). This is often one root cause for lots of headache when dealing with transforms. A clear and concise notation would definitively help.

PS: Interesting [post](https://www.hepeng.me/ros-tf-whoever-wrote-the-python-tf-api-f-ked-up-the-concept/) that also mentions the inconsistencies.

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2022-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2